# PHP - Retrieve Facebook image in Google Compute Engine

Tags: php, facebook, curl, google-compute-engine, file-get-contents

I've tried to retrieve the image data of my Facebook profile picture, using both file_get_contents and curl.

The problem occurs on my Google compute engine instance, while on any other server (localhost - mamp, AWS) the script works fine.

An example for one of the scripts I was using

```
<?php

var_dump(
    json_decode(
        file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/_FACEBOOK_ID_/picture?width=720&height=720")
    )
);
```

Please keep in mind that I've tried using the parameter *redirect=false*, and accessing the image url I've got in my json response returned false as-well.

Also, I've tried using *wget* in SSH to the image's url, which returned (403) Forbidden.

My assumption is that I need to configure something differently in my server, not PHP, but because I'm able to retrieve any other image, with the same script - I'm not sure what.

Comment: Some websites refuse to deliver Content if no valid user-agent is set. I once had that problem and solved it with setting a Firefox User Agent Header within curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already experienced this exact problem,
Ignoring SSL verification while using cURL did the trick for me.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Ignore SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/_FACEBOOK_ID_/picture?width=720&height=720");
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data);
```