# cURL not working on Google Compute engine

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm facing a similar issue to this question on my VM instance that runs WordPress:

> [PHP - Retrieve Facebook image in Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38014596/php-retrieve-facebook-image-in-google-compute-engine)

I'm using AJAX to call `send_otp.php` with `mobile_number` as a parameter.

My `send_otp.php` script is:

```
$mobile_number = $_POST['mobile_number'];
//  Don't do in production, possible RCE
$url = "http://gateway.com/api?numbers=" . $mobile_number. "";
//      Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification (Don't do in production)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Execute
$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);
    
$result = json_decode($result, true);
```

And my Javascript code is as follows:

```
cust_mob = jQuery('#number');
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'send_otp.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        mobile_nuber: '' + cust_mob.val().toString() + '',
        security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('mobile-validate-nonce'); ?>'
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('success');
    }, error: function (response) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

I've removed a lot of code just to post it here and everything works fine on my local machine WordPress installation using WAMP.

This code is a part of my theme and all I'm doing is zipping the theme folder and uploading it to WordPress after making changes. Everything works fine except this 'curl' part e.g. login using ajax and updating profile using AJAX is working fine.

Please tell me how to resolve it, or are there any other methods to achieve the same?

Comment: is curl installed on your vps? what error are you getting? did you check the apache error log?

Comment: if the ajax never completes, it is likely that curl is just trying to connect and hasn't timed out. Try setting a timeout. Check a phpinfo page to confirm that the curl plugin is installed. Also add some logging in there to see how far you have gotten through the script to find where you are pausing and once again, check the apache error log as that is where all php errors go, including ones you don't see.

Comment: yes, I would suggest double checking the url is correct and try using curl to hit a different site. This will help show if the issue is that specific host you are trying to contact or something else.

Comment: were you able to reach any other url? If you run the php script on the command line does it work? Have you tried using file_get_contents to access a url? What about using the command line and wget or curl, do any of those get out to another site?

Comment: you could try installing curl. GCE is just a vm so you have full control over what is installed. If using ubuntu `sudo apt-get install php-curl` or `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl` if it wants the version. I personally am using a PPA to run php7 and have to specify 7.0 in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this lib: https://github.com/azayarni/purl

I use it in my pet-project that hosted on GAE platform and it works fine.